# Is there a way to detect which MutationObserver a callback was called from?

Tags: callback, mutation-observers, dom4

If I have a single callback function and two [MutationObservers](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#mutation-observers) for two different dom nodes, is there a way to tell which observer triggered the callback when it is called? The work the callback needs to perform is substantially similar, so creating one for each observer seems undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

The specific `MutationObserver` is supplied as the 2nd argument to the callback.  See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: Thanks. I missed that line. I think I did something basically similar to that. However, instead of explicitly defining the callbacks arguments and checking `if(2ndarg == observer1)`, I checked `if(this == observer1)` since `this` in the execution context of the callback seemed to be the observer.